# Data in DB in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My friend asked this question I am not sure why it is on my StackOverflow profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails supports a technique called counter cache, where you can store the number of messages, comments or anything you want, without executing redundant commands.

There is a railscast that describes it very nicely :

http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

If you, however, need to stick to a cron based task, it would be very easy to store the count yourself in a statistics model like :

```
Statistic.new
Statistic.total_users = User.count 
Statistic.total_comments = Comment.count 
Statistic.save
```

Comment: you can write a simple rails task to do it for you(more on it http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks). It would be an entry to the Statistic model, yes. But the code to be executed would be in the Rake Task.